# DropDownList Items - Free hours

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms

I want have on my DropDownList.Items not occupied hours.

I have in my database a table:

> Visit: visitID, trainerID,clientID,Data,Hour.

When customer want add a new visit he must choose a trainer, the date and click on button "Check avaible hours". Then on DropDownList.Items should be not occupied hours.

For example - all hours: 9:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00. In table are two visitis on selected date: 9:00 and 12:00, so client during adding new visit should see on DropDownList free hours: 10:00,11:00,13:00,14:00.

This code add to DropDownList.Items occupied hours from database:

```
using (myEntities dc = new myEntities())
{

   var hours = (from a in dc.Visits
                  where  (a.Data == TextBox1.Text && a.trainerID.Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
                  orderby a.Hour
                  select new 
                  {
                      a.visitID,
                      a.Hour,
                  });        
    DropDownList2.DataSource = hours.ToList();
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Hour";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "visitID";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You say what you want, you show what you tried. That's great. Now what's the problem?

Comment: Now i have in DropDownItems occupied hours from database.
My target is to have FREE hours (all without occupied). Now i have for example 3 visit in database on 11:00, 12:00, 13:00 and in dropdownlist.items i have the same 11:00, 12:00, 13:00. Its bad because i should have free hours (all without occupied).

Comment: Please edit your question. Also, make it clear from which data source you get "all" hours.

Comment: "All hours" I want enter manually without data source. Im still learning asp.net, dont be angry ;)

Comment: So maybe I should add "all hours" to any list and compare it with dropdownlist.items (occupied hours). Check if any item from list != dropdownlist.items -> add it to dropdownlist.item and remove the rest. I dont know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to display the sequence of available hours. You have a function that returns the collection of occupied hours.

Normally the collection of available hours equals the collection of all hours except the collection of occupied hours. As expected, the function that gives you this is called **Enumerable.Except**

```
IEnumerable<Hour> allHours = GetAllHours();
IEnumerable<Hour> occupiedHours = RetrieveOccupiedHours();
IEnumerable<Hour> availableHours = allHours.Except(occupiedHours);
```

To be able to use this you need the a class Hour. To make it possible for future changes to changes, consider using a different name than hour, for instance appointmentPeriod. This allows you to later change the appointmentperiod in periods of half hours or periods of fifty minutes, or whatever.

Once you have a class to represent an "hour" (appointment period), the function GetAllHours will be something like:

```
IEnumerable<Hour> GetHoursOnDate(DateTime Date)
{
    // something difficult making sure that 3 o' clock in the middle of the night
    // is not considered as an available hour, nor the hours on Christmas day
    // and possible also not Sundays, Easter day, New Year's eve at 0:0 etc.
}

private void OnDropDown_ComboBoxAvailableHours(object sender, ...)
{
    DateTime selectedDate = GetSelectedDate();
    IEnumerable<Hour> hoursOnSelectedDate = GetHoursOnDate(selectedDate);
    IEnumerable<Hour> occupiedHoursOnSelectedDate = RetrieveOccupiedHours(date);
    IEnumerable<Hour> availableHoursOnSelectedDate = hoursOnSelectedDate
        .Except(occupiedHoursOnSelectedDate);

    comboBoxAvailableHours.Items.Clear();
    comboBoxAvailableHours.Items.AddRange(availableHoursOnSelectedDate
        .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Omg thank you. But i think its too hard for me... Maybe is any simpler way?

Comment: What is too difficult? The concept of hour? Or the concept to prevent appointments on Christmas day? The latter is indeed difficult. Alas if you have difficult specifications than the code will be difficult. You can of course simplify the specifications by making it possible to create an appointment 24/7, but I hardly believe that is acceptable

Comment: Its only project to my school, its not application for real company :)